# Swift 2.0 - Unable to Write to Text File (OS X)

Tags: swift, nsstring, writetofile

I have a text file that I will be reading and writing to.  I have gotten the code to read successfully, but am unable to write to the text file again.  I want to overwrite everything (not amend).

```
    if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("airports.txt")

        var strTextToWrite:String = String()        
        strTextToWrite = "Test"

        do {
            try strTextToWrite.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        }
        catch { print("Error") }

    }
```

The above code doesn't throw an error (i.e. the word 'Error' isn't printed as per my catch code), but the text file remains unedited, retaining the value it had before the code was run.

The text file is contained inside the X-Code project as shown below:

[image: Text File Location]

I'm at a real loss here, I don't understand why the code isn't working.  I have confirmed that it is being run (by printing the value of `strTextToWrite` before and after the `do` statement, and it is definitely running through the `do` block of code because it isn't being caught by the `catch` block.  The only thing I can think of is that the code is pointing at the wrong file (but the file name is correct, as you can verify with the screenshot above).

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at 2 different files? Right-click on `airport.txt` in Xcode and choose *Show in Finder* to see where it is. The one your code writes to is at `~/Documents/airport.txt`

Comment: Show your code for the reading of the file.

Comment: Thanks @CodeDifferent, I copied that code from a website and it obviously was under the assumption the file would be in the folder system of the computer.  Would you be able to post an answer showing how to reference the file within the main bundle of the app itself?  I have used code before but couldn't get the referencing to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at 2 different files: the one you write to is `~/Documents/airport.txt` while the one you see (and check) in Xcode is located in your project folder. To see the update, you need to *reference* the file in Xcode, not make a copy of it.

1. Right click `airport.txt` in your Project Navigator and click Delete > Move to Trash
2. Go to `~/Documents/airport.csv` and drag it into your Xcode project. Do not add it to any target and unselect "Copy Items if Necessary"

You now have created *a link* to the file.

[image]

Modifying files in your bundle is generally a bad idea. If you need a place to output a temporary file, use the app's subfolder under `~/Application Support` or the system's temp folder.